# What's the net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR about?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, curl, http2

I'm currently working on a website, which triggers a `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200` error on Google Chrome. I'm not sure exactly what can provoke this error, I just noticed it pops out only when accessing the website in HTTPS. I can't be 100% sure it is related, but it looks like it prevents JavaScript to be executed properly.

For instance, the following scenario happens :

1. I'm accessing the website in HTTPS
2. My Twitter feed integrated via https://publish.twitter.com  isn't loaded at all
3. I can notice in the console the ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
4. If I remove the code to load the Twitter feed, the error remains
5. If I access the website in HTTP, the Twitter feed appears and the error disappears

Google Chrome is the only web browser triggering the error: it works well on both Edge and Firefox.
(NB: I tried with Safari, and I have a similar `kcferrordomaincfnetwork 303` error)

I was wondering if it could be related to the header returned by the server since there is this '200' mention in the error, and a 404 / 500 page isn't triggering anything.

Thing is the error isn't documented at all. Google search gives me very few results. Moreover, I noticed it appears on very recent Google Chrome releases; the error doesn't pop on v.64.X, but it does on v.75+ (regardless of the OS; I'm working on Mac tho).

---

Might be related to [Website OK on Firefox but not on Safari (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303) neither Chrome (net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927327/website-ok-on-firefox-but-not-on-safari-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-error-303-neit)

---

Findings from further investigations are the following:

- **error doesn't pop on the exact same page if server returns 404 instead of 2XX**
- error doesn't pop on local with a HTTPS certificate
- error pops on a different server (both are OVH's), which uses a different certificate
- error pops no matter what PHP version is used, from 5.6 to 7.3 (framework used : Cakephp 2.10)

As requested, below is the returned header for the failing ressource, which is the whole web page. Even if the error is triggering on each page having a HTTP header 200, those pages are always loading on client's browser, but sometimes an element is missing (in my exemple, the external Twitter feed). Every other asset on the Network tab has a success return, except the whole document itself.
[image: line that failed in console]

Google Chrome header (with error):

[image: Chrome header]

Firefox header (without error):

[image: Firefox header]

A `curl --head --http2` request in console returns the following success:

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Fri, 04 Oct 2019 08:04:51 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 127089
set-cookie: SERVERID31396=2341116; path=/; max-age=900
server: Apache
x-powered-by: PHP/7.2
set-cookie: xxxxx=0919c5563fc87d601ab99e2f85d4217d; expires=Fri, 04-Oct-2019 12:04:51 GMT; Max-Age=14400; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

---

Trying to go deeper with the chrome://net-export/ and https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com tools is telling me the request ends with a RST_STREAM :

```
t=123354 [st=5170]    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_RST_STREAM
                      --> error_code = "2 (INTERNAL_ERROR)"
                      --> stream_id = 1
```

For what I read in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736463/rst-stream-frame-in-http2), "*In HTTP/2, if the client wants to abort the request, it sends a RST_STREAM. When the server receives a RST_STREAM, it will stop sending DATA frames to the client, thereby stopping the response (or the download). The connection is still usable for other requests, and requests/responses that were concurrent with the one that has been aborted may continue to progress.
[...]
It is possible that by the time the RST_STREAM travels from the client to the server, the whole content of the request is in transit and will arrive to the client, which will discard it. However, for large response contents, sending a RST_STREAM may have a good chance to arrive to the server before the whole response content is sent, and therefore will save bandwidth.*"

The described behavior is the same as the one I can observe. But that would mean the browser is the culprit, and then I wouldn't understand why it happens on two identical pages with one having a 200 header and the other a 404 (same goes if I disable JS).

Comment: https://aboutssl.org/fix-google-chrome-error-err_ssl_protocol_error/ that's one out of 110 results -

Comment: I've been here obviously, and there are only client-side related answers, which can't be a solution.

Comment: does the error occur in non-chrome browsers? if not, how is it not a client-side (specifically the Chrum browser) issue?

Comment: It appears on Safari too. My point is I won't ask any visitor of my website to update his system time or to delete his host file to navigate on my website. There must be something related to the web app (code, ssl certificate, server conf...) that triggers the error for all visitors, and if at least I had a clue of what the error was even about, I could investigate and try some changes. It is more like Chrome is considering something is going wrong, when others browsers don't.

Comment: Likely a malformed HTTP response headers. Is the whole site not loading? Or just one or more assets? Can you edit the question to include the HTTP response headers shown in the http response for an asset that doesn’t load when using HTTP/2? And also the for Edge/Firefox where it works?

Comment: @BarryPollard Thanks for the reply, I added the requested elements.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong there so suspect it's not the main request. Also ignore the cookies thing - it's not that. Try this to see if you can figure t out: https://www.michalspacek.com/chrome-err_spdy_protocol_error-and-an-invalid-http-header

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was aware about the chrome://net-export/ but didn't know you could actually read the json properly. I again updated the post, investigations keep going...

Comment: Should be related to server sent events. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#receiving_events_from_the_server) you can find more details

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't figure out what exactly was happening, but I found a solution.

The **CDN feature of OVH** was the culprit. I had it installed on my host service but disabled for my domain because I didn't need it.

Somehow, when I enable it, everything works.

I think it forces Apache to use the HTTP2 protocol, but what I don't understand is that there indeed was an HTTP2 mention in each of my headers, which I presume means the server was answering using the right protocol.

So the solution for my very particular case was to enable the CDN option on all concerned domains.

If anyone understands better what could have happened here, feel free to share explanations.

Answer (score 99):

In my case it was - no disk space left on the web server.

Comment: interesting, for me the same, front webserver had disk full. seems like nginx does not catch this situation because there was nothing noticable in log.

Comment: Just to explain to anyone who is wondering why this results in a protocol error, because we also got something similar and were left wondering what's going on. The issue is that when there's no disk space left on the disk, some webservers (nginx definitely but maybe apache as well) are unable to send an entire response and usually just drop the request after the first "chuck" of the response is sent. This results in the content length header to not match the actual content received. This (as mentioned by @Xtendo) can result in an http2 protocol error.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I had the same issue (nginx).  We were not out of space, but it was 90% full.  This issue was happening only on pages with a lot of content (large reports with 600+ rows of content in a table).  Increasing the disk size in AWS solved the problem immediately.

Comment: Same here for .net core app hosted on linux server. nginx creates temp files on requests which needs to load data from sql and as @BrandonRohde told, it happened usually in large data contained pages.

Answer (score 49):

The fix for me was setting `minBytesPerSecond` in IIS to `0`. This setting can be found in `system.applicationHost/webLimits` in IIS's Configuration Editor. By default it's set to `240`.

[image]

It turns out that some webservers will cut the connection to a client if the server's data throughput to the client passes below a certain limit. This is to protect against "slow drip" denial of service attacks. However, this limit can also be triggered in cases where an innocent user requests many resources all at once (such as lots of images on a single page), and the server is forced to ration the bandwidth for each request so much that it causes one or more requests to drop below the throughput limit, which causes the server to cut the connection and shows up as `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in Chrome.

For example, let's say you request 10 GIF images all at once, and each GIF is 10 megabytes (100MB total). If your download speed from the server is 1MB per second, your browser will have to divide that 1MBps amongst the 10 images somehow. Now, here is where it gets interesting, as how the bandwidth gets divided seems to be random:

1. Your browser may divide the bandwidth equally across the images, resulting in 0.1MBps allocated to each image. None of the download speeds fall below the default IIS `minBytesPerSecond` limit of 240 bytes, so all the GIFs download successfully.
2. Your browser may prioritize the first 5 at 0.2MBps, and put the last 5 "on hold" at 0MBps, to be downloaded after the first 5. However, since 0MBps is below the default IIS `minBytesPerSecond` limit of 240 bytes, the server cuts the connection to the remaining downloads.

I was able to stop the connections from being cut by following these steps:

1. I used Chrome's *Network Log Export* tool at `chrome://net-export/` to see exactly what was behind the `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error. I started the log, reproduced the error, and stopped the log.
2. I imported the log into the log viewer at https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/#import, and saw an interesting event titled `HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_RST_STREAM`, with error code `8 (CANCEL)`.

[image]

3. I did some Googling on the term "RST_STREAM" (which appears to be an abbreviated form of "reset stream") and found a discussion between some people talking about an IIS setting called `minBytesPerSecond` (discussion here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aeb01c46-bcdf-40ed-a417-8a3558221137). I also found another discussion where there was some debate about whether `minBytesPerSecond` was intended to protect against slow HTTP DoS (slow drip) attacks (discussion here: [IIS 8.5 low minBytesPerSecond not working against slow HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582362)). In any case, I learned that IIS uses `minBytesPerSecond` to determine whether to cancel a connection if it cannot sustain the minimum throughput. This is relevant in cases where a single user makes many requests to a large resource, and each new connection ends up starving all the other unfinished ones, to the point where some may fall below the `minBytesPerSecond` threshold.
4. To confirm that the server was canceling requests due to a `minBytesPerSecond` error, I checked my server's *HTTPERR* log at `c:\windows\system32\logfiles\httperr`. Sure enough, I opened the file and did a text search for "MinBytesPerSecond" and there were tons of entries for it.

[image]

5. So after I changed the `minBytesPerSecond` to `0`, I was no longer able to reproduce the `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error. So, it appears that the `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error was being caused by my server (IIS) canceling the request because the throughput rate from my server fell below the `minBytesPerSecond` threshold.

So for all you reading this right now, if you're not using IIS, maybe there is a similar setting related to minimum throughput rate you can play with to see if it gets rid of the `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error.

Comment: Great explanation. Here is the link for official documentation on IIS Web Limits  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/weblimits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/weblimits)

Answer (score 32):

I am finally able to solve this error after researching some things I thought is causing the error for 24 errors. I visited all the pages across the web. And I am happy to say that I have found the solution. 
If you are using NGINX, then set gzip to off and add `proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;` in the server block like I have shown below.

```
 server {
  ...
  ...
  gzip off;
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
  ....
```

Why? Because what actually happening was all the contents were being compressed twice and we don't want that, right?!

Comment: Appreciate this! I think turning `gzip` off in my particular case was the missing step. I am running an express app behind nginx, and would only get the error on the `.css/.js`, not always either, maybe 1/2 the time. This did the trick!

Comment: Just 
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0; statement work fine for me.

Comment: I had this problem with Vite and it caused pages to no load with messages of missing source maps. Thank you!

Comment: gzip makes transferring files faster. Any workarounds here?

Comment: In my case, gzip was happening twice, and hence I set it off here.

Comment: Had a completely different issue, actually a malformed header. Used your debug method and it made it obvious that HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_INVALID_HEADER was the problem. Really great description of the method.

Answer (score 30):

For several weeks I was also annoyed by this "bug":

```php
net :: ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
```

In my case, it occurred on images generated by PHP.

It was at `header()` level, and on this one in particular:

```php
header ('Content-Length:'. Filesize($cache_file));
```

It did obviously not return the exact size, so I deleted it and everything works fine now.

So Chrome checks the accuracy of the data transmitted via the headers, and if it does not correspond, it fails.

#### EDIT

I found why `content-length` via `filesize` was being miscalculated: the `GZIP` compression is active on the PHP files, so excluding the file in question will fix the problem. Put this code in the `.htaccess`:

```php
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^ / thumb.php no-gzip -vary
```

It works and we keep the header `Content-length`.

Comment: Great you saved me !!! But I still don't understand the real problem, in my case the error only happens in https but not in http.

Comment: Hello @Nico , yes, I think it's normal, the verification between the announced size and that of the file downloaded by the browser (Chrome) should only be done in the https protocol. Very happy that this solution could help you!

Comment: Somehow I managed to use "Content -Length" instead of "Content-Length". After removing the space, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I had a problem with Livewire not loading its JS in shared hosting, while I could open the same path in the browser without problem. I don't understand why this worked, but it did. Black magic. Thank you.

Comment: > It did obviously not return the exact size, so I deleted it and everything works fine now.

This fix worked for me. In C# I did this:

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = null;
```

Answer (score 18):

I experienced a similar problem, I was getting ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR on one of the HTTP GET requests.

I noticed that the Chrome update was pending, so I updated the Chrome browser to the latest version and the error was gone next time when I relaunched the browser.

Comment: Me too, and this answer is the only one that makes sense, because it's not specific to a single website, or a site I own, but just arbitrary sites.

Comment: This is not the only possible source of this problem. But it's good to check if you have the last version.

Answer (score 10):

I encountered this because the http2 server **closed the connection** when sending a big response to the Chrome.

Why?
Because it is just a setting of the http2 server, named **WriteTimeout**.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem when having a Nginx server that exposing the node-js application to the external world. The Nginx made the file (css, js, ...) compressed with `gzip` and with Chrome it looked like the same.

The problem solved when we found that the node-js server is also compressed the content with gzip. In someway, this double compressing leading to this problem. Canceling node-js compression solved the issue.

Comment: It is interesting to see that several persons have answered this post already, and each time the root of the problem was something different. I think this error is quite confusing indeed.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that my access token was too large, making the header also too large, so I refactored its content to fix the error

Comment: This was my issue too. I had multiple sites running on localhost all storing cookies there. You only need a handful of access tokens to exceed the default 16KB maxrequestbytes setting.

Comment: This was also my issue.  In development we had a concept of a superuser who had all roles, which worked for 8 years.  When the number of roles reached a certain threshold this suddenly broke - but it was because our access token was now too large.  This answer pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

We experienced this problem on pages with long Base64 strings. The problem occurs because we use CloudFlare.

Details: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/err-http2-protocol-error/119619.

Key section from the forum post:

> After further testing on Incognito tabs on multiple browsers, then
>   doing the changes on the code from a BASE64 to a real .png image, the
>   issue never happened again, in ANY browser. The .png had around 500kb
>   before becoming a base64,so CloudFlare has issues with huge lines of
>   text on same line (since base64 is a long string) as a proxy between
>   the domain and the heroku. As mentioned before, directly hitting
>   Heroku url also never happened the issue.

The temporary hack is to disable HTTP/2 on CloudFlare.

Hope someone else can produce a better solution that doesn't require disabling HTTP/2 on CloudFlare.

Comment: We experience same thing but not because of cloudflare: we just had too many long base64 string image

Answer (score 3):

I faced this error several times and, it was due to transferring large resources(larger than 3MB) from server to client.

Comment: Have you got any resolution on that? If yes can please share how you resolved it.

Comment: @UtkarshaG compressed and minified css,js files.

Comment: this is happening to me because I have a select2 with ~4000 SelectListItems (Key-value pairs) in it. Out of nowhere, I just started getting the HTTP2 protocol error on first load. When I hit refresh page loads fine on second time. I'm only passing 193kb of data but maybe protocol doesn't like huge select lists.

Answer (score 3):

This error is currently being fixed: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2001234

But it helped me, changing nginx settings:

- turning on gzip;
- add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
- expires off;

In my case, Nginx acts as a reverse proxy for Node.js application.

Comment: this answer worked for me too. Follow this link https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/ for proper syntax

Answer (score 3):

Seems like many issues may cause `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR`: in my case it was a minor syntax error in a php-generated header, `Content-Type : text/plain` . You might notice the space *before* the colon... that was it. Works no problem when the colon is right next to the header name like `Content-Type: text/plain`. Only took a million hours to figure out... The error happens with Chrome only, Firefox loaded the object without complaint.

Comment: My head hurt reading this out of pure empathy

Answer (score 3):

Just posting here to let people know that ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Chrome can also be **caused by an unexpected response to a CORS request**.

In our case, the **OPTIONS request was successful**, but **the following PUT** that should upload an image to our infrastructure **was denied with a 410** (because of a missing configuration allowing uploads) resulting in Chrome issuing a ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

When checking in Firefox, the error message was much more helpful:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.[...] (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 410.`

My recommendation would be to check an alternative browser in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In my case `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200` was caused by (AWS) load balancer that terminates idle connections after 60 seconds.

> **If no data has been sent or received by the time that the idle timeout period elapses**, the load balancer closes the connection. To ensure that lengthy operations such as file uploads have time to complete, send at least 1 byte of data before each idle timeout period elapses, and increase the length of the idle timeout period as needed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout

And terminated connection was a long polling [vaadin](/questions/tagged/vaadin) [vaadin8](/questions/tagged/vaadin8) endpoint, that sends no data if there is no events on the backend. More about this on this blog post https://mvysny.github.io/Vaadin8-push-issues/ which helped me a lot.

**The solution that I used** was setting context param `pushLongPollingSuspendTimeout` to `58000` in `web.xml`

Comment: I think I have the same issue. Do you have a good fix? Either A) what ALB idle timeout do I need to keep the browser happy? or B) what setting do I change to make the browser not try to keep idle connections for more than 60s?

Comment: Thanks! My client is a web browser (+ some kind of corporate HTTP proxy) and my server is Scala Play (no long polling) so I'll have to look for something else to change, but thanks for updating.

Answer (score 2):

In our case, the reason was invalid header.
As mentioned in Edit 4:

- take the logs
- in the viewer choose *Events*
- chose *HTTP2_SESSION*

Look for something similar:

> **HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_INVALID_HEADER**
>
> --> error = "Invalid character in header name."
>
> --> header_name = "**charset=utf-8**"

Comment: What precisely does "take the logs" mean? The logs of what? ngiix? Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

By default nginx limits upload size to 1MB.

With `client_max_body_size` you can set your own limit, as in

```
location /uploads {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

You can set this setting also on the http or server block instead ([See here](https://www.tecmint.com/limit-file-upload-size-in-nginx/#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20Nginx%20has%20a,http%2C%20server%20or%20location%20context.&text=Set%20in%20http%20block%20which,server%20blocks%20(virtual%20hosts).)).

This fixed my issue with net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score 1):

I hit this issue working with Server Sent Events. The problem was solved when I noticed that the domain name I used to initiate the connection included a trailing slash, e.g. `https://foo.bar.bam/` failed with `ERR_HTTP_PROTOCOL_ERROR` while `https://foo.bar.bam` worked.

Comment: I also have the error message after SSE runs for a while and then suddenly it appears in the Chrome dev console. The trailing slash is, unfortunately, not the solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it depends on how the server handles routing. I haven't yet looked into these controls from within node / express

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what's going on. Since there is often a 504 timeout in the console, I guess that the PHP script aborts due to the limit of the execution time. For debugging I started to catch as many errors as possible and echo according messages to the frontend. Because each error/exception stops the SSE PHP script.

Comment: It could even be related to this: [SSE (EventSource) times out after 1 hour 22 minutes. Is there any way to keep it persistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19778231/1066234)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced this was the issue but through cPanel I'd noticed the PHP version was on 5.6 and changing it to 7.3 seemed to fix it. This was for a WordPress site. I noticed I could access images and generic PHP files but loading WordPress itself caused the error.

Comment: And yet, thank you for posting this Ric! This solved my problem. I was on 7.2, and moving it to 7.4 fixed it. Something weird WordPress must be doing.

Answer (score 1):

If simply restarting e.g., Chrome Canary, with a fresh profile fixes the problem, then one surely
is the ["victim" of a failed Chrome Variation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1207022#c13)! Yes, there are ways to opt out of being a [Guinea pig](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1127060#c34) in Chrome's field testing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case
header params can not set null or empty string

```
{
 'Authorization': Authorization  //Authorization can't use null or ''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that Bitdefender provided me with a local ssl certificate, when the website was still without a certificate.

When I disabled Bitdefender and reloaded the page, the actual valid server ssl certificate was loaded, and the ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue in C# NET Core 6. I was writing results to the body response with the method `WriteAsync` and returning with `Task.CompletedTask`

Like below:

```
await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("something to return");
return Task.CompletedTask;
```

And changed it to the code below:

```
 await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("something to return");
 return ctx.Response.CompleteAsync();
```

And it works fine now.

Apparently, you need to tell the Response object that you finished editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the long list of seemingly arbitrary causes, here is mine:

#### Scenario

- Migrating a 32 bit classic ASP website running on Windows Server 2012 that does use the 32 bit MDB OleDB drivers to access an Access DB.
- Migrating to a Windows Server 2022.
- Trying to improve things and installing the [64 bit OleDB MDB drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920), changing the connection string from `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` to `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` then running the application in a 64 bit App Pool in IIS.

This causes random `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` errors because of the App Pool crashing.

#### How to fix

The fix was:

- Uninstall the 64 bit MDB OleDB drivers.
- Install the 32 bit MDB OleDB drivers.
- Switch the App Pool to 32 bit again.

I do hope I finally find the time to migrate all this to some modern ASP.NET Core, but for now this was the fastest fix.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue (asp, c#  - HttpPostedFileBase) when posting a file that was larger than 1MB (even though application doesn't have any limitation for file size), for me the simplification of model class helped. If you got this issue, try to remove some parts of the model, and see if it will help in any way. Sounds strange, but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing this problem for the last week now as I've been trying to send DELETE requests to my PHP server through AJAX. I recently upgraded my hosting plan where I now have an SSL Certificate on my host which stores the PHP and JS files. Since adding an SSL Certificate I no longer experience this issue. Hoping this helps with this strange error.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error and I believe there can be multiple reasons behind it. Mine was, ARR was getting timed-out.

In my case, browser was making a request to a reverse proxy site where I have set my redirection rules and that proxy site is eventually requesting the actual site. Now for huge data it was taking more than 2 minutes 5 seconds and Application Request Routing timeout for my server was set to 2 minutes. I fixed this by increasing the ARR timeout by below steps:
1. Go to IIS
2. Click on server name
3. Click on Application Request Routing Cache in the middle pane
4. Click Server Proxy settings in right pane
5. Increase the timeout
6. Click Apply

Answer (score 0):

My team saw this on a single javascript file we were serving up. Every other file worked fine. We switched from `http2` back to `http1.1` and then either `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` or `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`. We ultimately discovered that there was a corporate filter (Trustwave) that was erroneously detecting an "infoleak" (we suspect it detected something in our file/filename that resembled a social security number). Getting corporate to tweak this filter resolved our issues.

Answer (score 0):

For my situation this error was caused by having circular references in json sent from the server when using an ORM for parent/child relationships. So the quick and easy solution was

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore })
```

The better solution is to create DTOs that do not contain the references on both sides (parent/child).

Answer (score 0):

I had another case that caused an ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR that hasn't been mentioned here yet.  I had created a cross reference in IOC (Unity), where I had class A referencing class B (through a couple of layers), and class B referencing class A.  Bad design on my part really.  But I created a new interface/class for the method in class A that I was calling from class B, and that cleared it up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was WordPress that now requires PHP 7.4 and I was running 7.2.
As soon as I updated, the errors disappeared.

---

Happened again and this time it was the ad-blocker that didn't like the name of my images (`yt.png`, `ig.png`, `url.png`). I added a prefix and all loaded ok.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (nginx on windows proxying an app while serving static assets on its own) page was showing multiple assets including 14 bigger pictures; those errors were shown for about 5 of those images exactly after 60 seconds; in my case it was a default send_timeout of 60s making those image requests fail; increasing the send_timeout made it work

I am not sure what is causing nginx on windows to serve those files so slow - it is only 11.5MB of resources which takes nginx almost 2 minutes to serve but I guess it is subject for another thread

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the time on my computer (browser client) was out of date, synced it using settings in windows, and then the error got away

Answer (score 0):

I had line breaks in my Content-Security-Policy in my nginx.conf that produced this error when used in an docker container running in Kube in GCP (serving angular but I doubt that matters).

Putting them all back on the same line and the problem went away.

A curl -v helped diagnose.

```
 http2 error: Invalid HTTP header field was received: frame type: 1, stream: 1, name: [content-security-policy], value: [script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self....
```

It was much easier to edit on separate lines but never again!

Answer (score 0):

Just writing to help someone with the same scenario. I use .NET Core 6 API + Angular 13. The problem was with my JSON serializer options max depth. I increased it and the problem was fixed.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.maxdepth?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Our ASP.Net application was throwing the same error. Other applications on the same server using the same SSL certificate were running fine.

Inexplicably, it turns our the error was due to the SQL Server Express database reaching it's limit of 10GB. We found the error in the Windows error log.

Clearing some tables and reducing the DB size solve the error!!

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue and what I did was just simply go to Help > About Google Chrome and update the to the latest version.

After the updating process done, this error will disappear and I can browse anything I want as usual again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (HTTPS protocol, PHP) the reason was:

wrong 404 header (

```
header('404 Not found', true);
```

instead of

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not found', true);
```

) - legacy from previous web developer.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the browser cache. It did not work.
Then I flush the dns cache by `ipconfig /flushdns`. It work!

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also occur when you have an **application pool recycle** (in IIS) while loading a page that takes a long time to load (e.g., it contains complex queries that take time to execute).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the way to send the file via `Express` server on `nodejs`.
This code was working fine on one server, but not on another:

```js
const fileName = 'тест.txt'
const fileContent = 'test'
res.set({"Content-Disposition":`attachment; filename="${require('utf8').encode(fileName)}"`})
res.send(fileContent)
```

so this code was causing the error ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR but only in Chrome by the way. It was working fine in Firefox or curl.

And this is the fix, that working fine on Chrome also.

```js
const fileName = 'тест.txt'
const fileContent = 'test'
res.attachment(fileName)
res.send(fileContent)
```

So the real reason maybe someone will post in comment.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was completely different to all of those mentioned here, interestingly though the browser does not mention what the actual issue was. For me was the `preflight` request the server configuration was not allowing this method which in turn is `OPTIONS` I once I've added this option to allow everything start working!

Hope that help someone stumble upon this if facing the same issues as me!

Answer (score 0):

For me was that the config "Private memory usage" was enabled and with a low value... When the IIS blocked the usage for that pool, the pool was recycled, and I got the error.

I could disable that limitation or increase it.

To reach the config, go to:

1. Application pools
2. Select the desired pool
3. Recycling...
4. Private memory usage (in KB)

Note: I'm using IIS + .NET Framework application, but it could be useful for any application hosted on IIS.

[image: recycle conditions]

Answer (score -2):

For those landing from search engines.

I had this issue recently, albeit not PHP, rather .NET and Angular. I tried the vast majority of suggestions here and on the MS support forums for IIS etc. In the end I had to reinstall / repair IIS Express via the old control panel (this restores the development certificate, I don't actually use IIS Express) and disable HTTP/2 under the HTTPS binding for the application. Of course, this is for a development environment only.

Comment: Yes, simply disabling HTTPS (Uncheck Enable SSL in Application>Properties>Debug) will fix the problem. But if you want to continue to use HTTPS you might want to dig deeper.

Answer (score -2):

maybe HDD is fill fully.
try clean.

Comment: This was my issue