# how to fix error :net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I'm making a application in `.NET Core` ,suddenly this error shows:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

and I cannot load my data from database`.JSON` have some problems.
This is photo of this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/78sGc.jpg

I didn't change anything in my code, suddenly this happened and I cannot find solution.
I read this:
[whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about) but this didn't help.
This is .Net Core fault ?

On every browser I have this problem

Comment: Does this happen for specific route only? Would you like to share some code? What version of ASP.NET Core do you use?

Comment: I am using .Net Core 2.1 >Everything works fine ,but suddenly this error show Here I am loading JSON ```function preload() {

    let url = '/Boards/Json';
    httpGet(url, 'json', function (response) {
        flag = true;
        json_object = response;
        setup();
    });
}``` this worked but now It do not load any data

Answer (score 5):

FWIW - it's related to the size of the JSON data being loaded. 
I'm getting it in Chrome on a Mac and don't have a fix. On Safari on Mac I get kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.

Comment: Hi, did you find any fix for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember, it's a long time ago and I have moved on.

Comment: Ok, if you by chance remember kindly post here :)