# ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR how to fix this error

Tags: php, apache, server

```
 The web page at https://www.mydomain/login.php might be temporarily
 down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
 ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

but i check online my domain

> HeaderHTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

using appache server

Comment: What did you do, why did this happen, please elaborate a bit more. And also research a bit more please

Comment: Make sure your domain name is resolved. Wait for a few hours for it to be resolved, hope this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about
 helps you.