# HTTP2 Protocol Error while loading the website

Tags: google-chrome, .net-core, angular5, http2

I am facing an issue while loading the angular web app after any deployment and getting error like ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I am still confused about why this issue is coming again and again. Can anyone please help me with this issue.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Size of the client js file which gets auto-generated while building the angular web gets above 5MB size this error usually comes so if anyone facing the same error either optimize the code to bring down the size or manually minify the js file.

Comment: this cannot be, by any means be acceptable answer. js files can be larger without ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR