# Get PDF file from server failed with: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, download

I want to allow the user to download and open a PDF file in a new window.

The first request sent to the server receives a status code of 200 but after the file was downloaded the request failed with `net :: ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200`

After the first request other requests working fine(from cache)

my code:

```
const openPdf= (url) => {
  const headers = new Headers({
    ...some application headers,
  });

return fetch(`www.example.com`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
    credentials: 'include',
  }).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {
       const file = new Blob([blob], {
          type: "application/pdf"
       });
       const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
       window.open(fileURL);
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what exact headers are you sending?

Comment: @AtinSingh  just headers related to the authorization nothing else...

Comment: Ah.. my bad. I thought your API was throwing that error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about   Does this help you?