# Eror while fetching data in javascript (ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using the js `fetch()` function to access to my API but I get the error

> POST mywebsite net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

My API work perfectly with my Android app, and this error appear when I add a bearer token to the header

```
call(url, formBody, callback) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: this.getHeader(),
        body: formBody,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => {
            callback(result)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error', error)
                });
}getHeader() {
    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer   " + this.getValidToken())
    return myHeaders;
}
```

I have tried with `xmlhttprequest` It's the same error.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about) help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the net::ERR\_HTTP2\_PROTOCOL\_ERROR about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about)

Comment: Not really because I don't understand how to solve it...