# iis two domain with ssl cert error browsing webpage

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl-certificate

I have iis 10.0 which host two domains ssl cert, say 1 is [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) and the another is [www.dfg.com](http://www.dfg.com), both domain are pointing to the same iis. So I can access webpage like https://www.rgx.com/calculation.aspx and
https://www.dfg.com/calculation.aspx both. The problem is that for most page, both domain work properply, but for some webpage in one domain e.g dfg.com https://www.dfg.com/questions.aspx, it cannot be loaded, in firefox, it returns

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

So what is the reason that some page cannot be accessed in one domain but can in another domain?

Comment: Did you check the certificate mappings in HTTP API? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background You can also run SSL Diag reports to learn more https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an error code? This error seems to only appear in Firefox, try the following in Firefox to see if it resolves the issue on your end:

1. Open about:preferences#privacy in the browser.
2. Scroll down to the Certificates section and click on "View certificates".
3. Make sure the Authorities tab is selected.
4. Locate Avast certificates and use the delete option to remove them.
5. Use the import button to import the certificates from C:\ProgramData\AVAST Software\Avast\wscert.dat.

Comment: It also happened in chrome. But the error message is different. How can I config chrome?

Comment: Please post your error message in chrome first, and then solve the problem according to the message.

Comment: chrome message ```The webpage at https://.../ReminderSettings.aspx?indicatortype=survey might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR```

Comment: Can you show me what your status code is? There are many reasons for this error. This is the link of a similar case with the issue: [ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about).

Comment: The status in network tab of chrome inspector is (failed)net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: The connection is changed for secure for insecure when accessing those asset in problem.