# Swagger UI Not Loading Sometimes

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, iis, swagger-ui, http2

I'm using latest version of Swagger in my ASPNetCore 3.1 project and debugging on latest version of Chrome. When I try to enter swagger page it sometimes not loading and i see an empty page. It looks like totally random. It solves after I refresh the page.

I saw these errors on console.

```
GET https://localhost:44389/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

index.html:95 Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
    at window.onload (index.html:95)
```

File in the error is random. Its sometimes a js file, sometimes a .css file. It changes.

If I publish this project on IIS and disable Http/2 support I never encounter this error.

Why?

Comment: Check the answers in this Q&A to see if they help: [What's the net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR about?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58215104/113116)

Comment: @Helen Unfortunately I've already tried all of these, nothing fixed : (

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following：

1.Check if all your controller methods have [http] tag. If they all do and still doesn't work go to step 2

2.In your configure function to ensure that you have app.UseStaticFiles(); If it still doesn't work go to step 3

3.Uninstall and reinstall swagger. If it doesn't work go to step 4 (Core Only)

4.If you are using Core Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles and reference it in your project.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried all of these, nothing fixed : (

Comment: Please check if swagger-ui-bundle.js is loaded. It is usually the case then the server is wrong configured and js files are not loaded

Comment: I already checked everything. When I continuously refresh swagger-UI page it sometimes loads without any problem, but sometimes it gives "net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR" on random .js and .css files.

Strange thing is why this problem disappear if I disable HTTP/2 from IIS settings?

Comment: Does it work with Edge/Firefox browser？This article can be helpful to you：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about

Comment: Yes, it is also happening in other browsers. Only solution I found is disabling http/2 or uninstalling KB5004476 Windows Update. Maybe it's a bug about OS.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, `SwaggerUIBundle is not defined`, and the problem is not on the web app that I'm developing but on my network. The problem was resolved after I switch to another network.