# ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR when load page.aspx running on IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, https, http2

I have a .net framework application running on IIS version 10.0.17763.1 hosted on an Azure Virtual Machine and sometimes my users are getting ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

> This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at https://..../page.aspx might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
> ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I have no idea how to debug and it's an intermittent issue

Below are two screenshots from the developer tools network tab

[image: network request]

[image: network header]

The only thing that is failing to load is the page.aspx, all the JS and CSS are loading properly.

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, you need to further analyze this error, you can refer to this link: [ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about).

Comment: Hi, check this [thread](https://forums.iis.net/t/1250683.aspx?ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR). They suggest to *enable https=- true in package.json file*

Comment: Was there a solution found to this problem?  We are having a similar problem - not everyone gets the error but we also don't know what the root cause is.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, someone has added a rule in URL rewrite section with string:

```
<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="***KHTML***" />
```

Removing this string solved the issue, because of HTML inside.