# net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 from chrome

Tags: nginx, http2

Hi all i'm currently receiving a `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200` and a bit stumped on what is causing the issue when testing my application. Frontend done in react and backend in golang. My application has been running successfully in the past few weeks but as of yesterday encountered this error and have been struggling to understand what causes the error or the main culprit. My application sits behind nginx.  When i visit the page and fails to load from the network tab on chrome i clearly see this error and not sure whats causing this error.

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 443 http2 ssl;                                                                                                                                                                           
        listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

        server_name myadminaccount.dev.me;
        ssl_certificate /Users/mylocal/.localcerts/full_chain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /Users/mylocal/.localcerts/private.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

When i access the logs from nginx, this is what i see below:

```
2021/08/01 16:50:46 [crit] 266#0: *233 open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx/proxy_temp/2/04/0000000042" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: myadminaccount.dev.me, request: "GET /main.js HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/main.js", host: "myadminaccount.dev.me", referrer: "https://myadminaccount.dev.me/"
2021/08/01 16:50:46 [error] 266#0: *233 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: myadminaccount.dev.me, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:4000/favicon.ico", host: "myadminaccount.dev.me", referrer: "https://myadminaccount.dev.me/"
```

I have googled the errors and came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about) but no success. Any suggestions is welcomed.