# REST API work on localhost but not on web hosting

Tags: php, api, rest, codeigniter

So this is my first time building a REST API and when I test the API using localhost it's working like a charm but when I host the REST API project on hosting suddenly it does not work. GET and POST functions still working but DELETE and PUT functions aren't.

I am using 000webhost free hosting as my test platform.

my delete function on Controller:

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $model = new BarangModel();
    $data = $model->where('id_barang', $id)->delete($id);
    if ($data) {
        $model->delete($id);
        $response = [
            'status'   => 200,
            'error'    => null,
            'messages' => [
                'success' => 'Barang berhasil dihapus!'
            ]
        ];
        return $this->respondDeleted($response);
    } else {
        return $this->failNotFound('No employee found');
    }
}
```

My model code:

```
class BarangModel extends Model
{
    protected $DBGroup              = 'default';
    protected $table                = 'tb_barang';
    protected $primaryKey           = 'id_barang';
    protected $useAutoIncrement     = true;
    protected $insertID             = 0;
    protected $returnType           = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes       = false;
    protected $protectFields        = true;
    protected $allowedFields        = ['kode', 'nama', 'merk', 'tahun', 'jumlah', "ruangan", 'penguasaan', 'keterangan'];

    // Dates
    protected $useTimestamps        = false;
    protected $dateFormat           = 'datetime';
    protected $createdField         = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField         = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField         = 'deleted_at';

    // Validation
    protected $validationRules      = [];
    protected $validationMessages   = [];
    protected $skipValidation       = false;
    protected $cleanValidationRules = true;

    // Callbacks
    protected $allowCallbacks       = true;
    protected $beforeInsert         = [];
    protected $afterInsert          = [];
    protected $beforeUpdate         = [];
    protected $afterUpdate          = [];
    protected $beforeFind           = [];
    protected $afterFind            = [];
    protected $beforeDelete         = [];
    protected $afterDelete          = [];
}
```

Error code in console:

```
Error: Network Error
    at t.exports (createError.js:16:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b.onerror (xhr.js:117:14)
ae @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1897
re @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1888
ne @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1848
(anonymous) @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1865
Promise.catch (async)
ie @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1865
n @ vue.runtime.esm.js:2188
ie @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1863
In.t.$emit @ vue.runtime.esm.js:3903
click @ VBtn.ts:163
ie @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1863
n @ vue.runtime.esm.js:2188
Qr.a._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js:6961

xhr.js:210          
DELETE https://xxx.000webhostapp.com/api/index.php/barang/106 net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
(anonymous) @ xhr.js:210
t.exports @ xhr.js:15
t.exports @ dispatchRequest.js:58
u.request @ Axios.js:108
i.forEach.u.<computed> @ Axios.js:129
(anonymous) @ bind.js:9
(anonymous) @ Barang.vue:292
u @ runtime.js:63
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:294
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:119
i @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
s @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
t @ Barang.vue:291
ie @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1863
n @ vue.runtime.esm.js:2188
ie @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1863
In.t.$emit @ vue.runtime.esm.js:3903
click @ VBtn.ts:163
ie @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1863
n @ vue.runtime.esm.js:2188
Qr.a._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js:6961
```

On postman, it shows a 'Socket hang up' error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about has a lot of different fixes for this issue

Comment: PUT and DELETE methods are not available with  free hosting on 000webhost. You have to upgrade to the Premium plan to use these HTTP methods. See [this post](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/delete-and-put-methods-not-working/61170)

Comment: OMG so that's the culprit. Thank you so much  @Jamie_D

Comment: You're welcome ... yes that's how they get you to break out your credit card ;)

Comment: Which is very amateurish  in my opinion because they could easily send a response header saying "only available with the premium plan" instead of just terminating the connection.

Comment: @Jamie_D why isn’t your comment an answer, so we can upvote it?

Comment: @zipzit Will do

Comment: Updated answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PUT and DELETE methods are not available with free hosting on [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/). You have to upgrade to the Premium plan to use HTTP methods other than GET and POST See [this post](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/delete-and-put-methods-not-working/61170).

All methods other than GET and POST are simply terminated with the free hosting plan. This is very amateurish on their part, in my opinion, because they could easily send a response header saying "only available with the premium plan" instead of just flat out terminating the connection.

Meanwhile developers are spending a monolithic waste of time trying to figure out what's wrong with their perfectly good code.