# VS 2022 / IIS Local Computer -> Not able to navigate to web pages

Tags: iis, iis-express

I work in VS 2022 with IIS Express.

I also sometimes publish to local IIS so I can test my web app to see how it will react with the customer.

When I use VS 2022 I see this for IIS Express:

[image]

When I try to use a virtual directory I see this for IIS on my system:

[image]

I've tried everything in this article: [What's the net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about)

I am on my work computer.

Can they push a group policy that can cause this?

When it started, I was trying to resolve an ongoing issue and was trying to use URL Rewrite. I saved a rule and all of a sudden this started happening.

Or maybe they pushed a policy to my computer?

Or did something change in my machine.config file?

Also, I noticed that my IPv4 DNS is this:

[image]

I also tried to create a new local cert for the IIS and bind it to that.

I am out of ideas?

VS 2022 was debugging and hitting more port fine earlier today.

What in the heck did I do to cause all of this?!?!?!

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Let your company open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com to ask Microsoft support to assist. Without touching that specific machine, it is impossible for anyone to know what's up.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with adding the URlWriter program to IIS.

I removed the program and everything worked.

Comment: If you can mark your answer, it will lead more people in the right direction.