# Laravel Filament Issue with https on prod server

Tags: https, http2, ovh, laravel-filament

Since I migrated my app (but its just a blank project for now) when I try to access the admin login page, I have issues both with Chrome & Firefox. On Chrome, messages are :

GET https://myapp/filament/assets/app.css?id=74b0e5d1ac0bd5c2e7700a3ab38b4202 net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
GET https://myapp/filament/assets/app.js?id=a89643d28638f3978429678585b1ce2d net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

No issue when in http only. Any advice ?
Thx a lot

- tried both http and https on local and distant (prod) server.
- tried on several Navigators (chrome & firefox)

Comment: Are you runing on nginx? Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about) for some insight.

Comment: Is there any space left on the VM your'e trying to run the project? Reference: [What's the net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about)