# Determine scope of ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED that reproduces to Web App that logs 302

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a reproduction of calling our authentication server hosted on an Azure Web App and receiving a `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` in the chrome console.  When I look at the web server logs, I see the exact response showing a correct `302` response.

I need help scoping the issue.

Am I correct that only something outside of the client can cause this?  Since I can reproduce this on any computer across networks / regions, am I correct the issue is between(exclusive) the Web API Server and the client? I exclude the Web Server because I see a `302` in the Web Server logs.

I have an open support request to MS Azure and haven't received a response for 6 days.  My last message was a brush-off and am trying to validate my assumptions to redirect my efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I received a different error with a different reproduction  `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

Access token being too large was culprit.

Different error led to this: [What's the net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about#answer-73873936)