# Why does a webpage work in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building a website using ASP.NET MVC. I have a page for user management so I name the page route as /usermanagement.

When it's running on local environment, everything works fine.

After I deployed it to the dev environment, the page shows "This site can’t be reached" error in chrome and Edge, but still works fine in Firefox.

```
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at https://mywebsite.com/user-management might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

At first, I thought it may be related to the specific URL path so I changed it to /user-management. The page loads initially and everything works fine. However, after a few minutes, when I go back and reopen the website, this page shows the same error. I have two routes defined for this UserManagementController:

```
    [Route("administration/user-management")]
    [Route("user-management")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The route `/user-management` doesn't work in Chrome (but works in Firefox) but `/administration/user-management` works in all browsers.

I can't figure out why this happens. Can anyone give me a hint?

- Update:

I noticed a weird thing. On my website, all other pages work fine. When I open the page `/usermanagement`, the page is actually navigated to chrome-error://chromewebdata/. I see a yellow warning message "VM45:5 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.". I checked the `window.location.href` in the console and it says `'chrome-error://chromewebdata/'`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about

Comment: Is this view using a JavaScript module that is not used in the other views that work?

Comment: @CristianRusanu, no, this view is doing the exact same thing as several other views have been doing.

Comment: Could it be Content-Security-Policy value that is causing the issue?

Comment: I fixed the issue by fixing a typo in the CSP value.