IIS "Disable HTTP/2" option still gets h2 requests
we have some old app we are supporting. There is a functionality which allows uploading photos. However, in some cases (specially using larger, multiple files), some requests end in ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR.
The obvious solution here is to make it work with HTTP/2 (and that's probably what we are going to do). Temporarily, we switched the "Disable HTTP/2" on in the IIS, which made things work as the requests now use HTTP/1.1
HOWEVER, we are getting reports, that in some rare cases, the requests are still using HTTP/2 which results in the above error. I am not able to simulate this locally or on our servers. Since the live server lives in an external provider, my best guest would be that the traffic runs through some proxies, etc. which can case the protocol to switch..
So my question is, how can this happen?
PS: Not that it matters, but the technology used is ASP.NET MVC (framework v4.8) along with KendoUI upload component in some very old version..

If you just disabled HTTP/2 on site bindings, then you accept the risks that somehow the incoming requests match another binding with HTTP/2 enabled, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/binding-diagnostics#background You might consider disabling HTTP/2 machine wide.

the requests are still using HTTP/2 which results in the above error, does it happen only on specific requests, or does it happen randomly?

@XudongPeng Unfortunately, from what I understand from the users, this happens totally randomly, even when the same steps using the same upload images are done, from the same browser, sometimes it just happens...

Please have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about, is it possible that there is a similar cause?
